# Capturing String Segments between Special Characters using Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string of text:

`textString1:textString2:textString3:textString4`

I'm looking to capture each text string and assign them to variables.

I've somehow managed to come up with the following:

```
var errorText = 'AAAA:BBBB:CCCC:DDDD';

var subString, intro, host, priority, queue = '';

var re = /(.+?\:)/g;
subString = errorText.match(re);
intro = subString[0];
host = subString[1];
priority = subString[2];
//queue = subString[3];

console.log(intro + " " + host + " " + priority);
```

[JS Bin Link](http://jsbin.com/vasiwi/1/edit)

However, I'm having problems with:

- capturing the last group, since there is no `:` at the end
- the variables contain `:` which I'd like to strip

Comment: Why don't you use `errorText.split(":")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a regex for this - just use `errorText.split(':')` to split by a colon. It will return an array.

And if you then want to add them together with spaces, you could do a simple replace instead: `errorText.replace(/:/g,' ')`.

Comment: Awesome, this seems much easier! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

use split method for this.it will return array of string then iterate through array to get string:

```
var errorText = 'AAAA:BBBB:CCCC:DDDD';
var strArr=errorText.split(':');
console.log(errorText.split(':'));
for(key in strArr){
    console.log(strArr[key]);
}
```